# Trying to identify a battery and its controller

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator

Attached are two images of the inside of one of those devices to extend the battery life of your phone. This one was a promotional giveaway and only had their logo on the outside. I tried searching for the text in the second image, but nothing that comes up is likely. I'm hoping there is something I am not realizing in the image that would help my research.

[image: The entire battery and controller]
[image: The backside of the board, with model number?]

!! Update !! I found another one. The little chip reads ETA9640 / 5486B.

Comment: No text written on the back side of the battery?

Comment: Did you attack the charger yourself? It certainly looks like a lithium polymer battery and probably 3.7v nominally.

Comment: Could you provide a macro photo of the chip on the little board? Or you just read it and post this info...

Comment: Sadly I disposed of it already; the battery was puffed up and broke the case.

Comment: Already puffed up?

Comment: @Unknown123: Yes it was inflating inside the shiney plastic and popped the case apart.

Comment: @smajli: Updated with chip info: ETA9640 / 5486B

Comment: Great. This is your answer. As you will read from the datasheet the controller is 1A max charger with battery 2.9V recharge treshold, 4.2 max voltage (typical values for Lithium battery). Also boost to 5V (to serve as USB power bank). Datasheet is very simplified, lacks the charging plots and is written in very simple language. Link: http://www.datasheet39.com/PDF/954817/ETA9640-datasheet.html